# Using Log Parser Studio and UrlScan Logs

Tags: iis, logparser, urlscan

I'm trying to view UrlScan 3.1 Logs in Log Parser Studio 2.  I have tried selecting urlscanlog as the log type but no results are returned.  I can use log parser directly from the command line and parse urlscan logs without any problem. Log Parser Studio is also working fine with IIS logs.  Can anyone else open UrlScan Logs in Log Parser Studio? If so, what settings are being used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all select TSVLOG as the log type. Then click on the gear symbol to the right of the log type. The iSeparator needs changing to space, the nSkip lines needs to be 4, and the header file needs pointing to a new file which contains only:

Date Time c-ip s-siteid cs-method cs-uri x-action x-reason x-context cs-data x-control

This is you setting that the separator is a space between each field, there are 4 lines in the log files to ignore at the start and then the header file contains the name of each field in the log file.

Once this was complete I was able to query urlscan logs in Log Parser Studio without a problem.